# how to create swift model for API response if response have "key" which have nil Value initially but its get filled with data type after sometime

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, structure

this is my API response from postman when "status" key value is open

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 247,
        "status": "open",
}
        "code": 1,
        "message": "Details fetched successfully."
}
```

and this is API response from same API when "status" key value get changed to "completed"

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 247,
         "status": “completed,
        "additional_data": {
            "id": 241,
            "booking_id": 247,
            "checklist_done": "{\"4\":\"Gear Oil\",\"2\":\"Engine Oil Change\"}",
            "work_with_price": "{}",
            "work_price": "0",
            "status": "pending"
      },
    
    "code": 1,
    "message": "Details fetched successfully."
}
```

so if you look on above response a new key "additional_data" get added to response.  what is the problem i am facing when "status"  is "open" i am able to decode data but when "status" changed to "completed" i am not able to decode data

here what i had tried
this is structure which i have created to decode API response

```
struct ServicingModel: Codable {
    var data: DataClass?
    var code: Int?
    var message: String?
}


struct DataClass: Codable {
    var id: Int?
    var status: String?
    var additionalData: AdditionalData?

 enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case status 
        case additionalData = "additional_data"
   }

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            id = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .id)
            status = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .status)

            if let additionalDataOpt = try values.decodeIfPresent(AdditionalData.self,        forKey: .additionalData) {
                additionalData = additionalDataOpt
            } else {
                additionalData = nil
            }
}

}

struct AdditionalData: Codable {
    var id, bookingID: Int?
    var checklistDone: String?
    var workWithPrice: String?
    var workPrice: String?
    var status: String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case bookingID = "booking_id"
        case checklistDone = "checklist_done"
        case workWithPrice = "work_with_price"
        case workPrice = "work_price"
        case status
}
}
```

by using above structure i am able to decode data when status is open but when status is changed to completed i am unable to decode data, please guide me how i can create model to for additional data to map API response when additional_data key get added.

i got stuck on this problem from last three days any help would be appreciated . thanks for advance

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid in the completed state. It has the wrong type of open quotes and is missing ending quotes.

Comment: take the advice the contributors have given you
 when you asked this question using your other fake account:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76089543/how-to-create-model-for-api-response-if-in-api-response-some-key-value-changes
 
 Use a `do/catch` around your `...try JSONDecoder()...` to decode your data and debug the error you get.

Comment: After fixing your incorrect json your code worked fine for me so whatever the issue is, it isn't part of the question. Unless of course the issue is incorrect json but I doubt that.

Comment: workingdog support Ukraine- i tried all the way from my end actually do catch block not gonna tell me what the problem behind decoding, uusing do catch didnt help me , sorry for invalid jason response , i tried to make sort because actual jSON response was big so no wanna gonna check every key

Comment: what error do you get, use `print(error) in the catch` , and show how you decode the server response. Show all the json response data, there is plenty of space, or at least a good representative set, not just the ad-hock bit that you show.

Comment: Does this answer your question (again): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76126396/how-to-create-model-to-decode-api-response-if-key-have-value-type-dictionary-of

Answer (score 0):

Notes:

- As mentioned by others the JSON is invalid.
- As you decode `additionalData` with `decodeIfPresent`, an `if` statement is not needed. If the key is missing `decodeIfPresent` returns `nil`.
- Declare only those properties as optional whose key can be missing.
- If you don't need to `encode` the data conform only to `Decodable`.
- If the properties won't be modified, declare them as `let` constants.
- A good practice is to decode `status` as `enum`.
- You can get rid of the `CodingKeys` in `AdditionalData` and the conversion `= "additional_data"` by applying the `convertFromSnakeCase` key decoding strategy.

---

```
struct ServicingModel: Decodable {
    var data: DataClass
    var code: Int
    var message: String
}

enum Status: String, Decodable {
    case open, completed
}

struct DataClass: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let status: Status
    let additionalData: AdditionalData?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, status, additionalData
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        status = try values.decode(Status.self, forKey: .status)
        additionalData = try values.decodeIfPresent(AdditionalData.self, forKey: .additionalData)
    }
}

struct AdditionalData: Decodable {
    let id, bookingId: Int
    let checklistDone, workWithPrice, workPrice, status: String
}
```

---

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
```